# Regular expression get IMG SRC from HTML

Tags: html, regex

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="panel-image listing-img">
      <a href="/rooms/854260?s=BD20" class="media-photo media-cover">
        <div class="listing-img-container media-cover text-center">
          <img itemprop="image" data-current="0" src="https://a2.muscache.com/ic/pictures/19208233/4d8e6c0d_original.jpg?interpolation=lanczos-none&amp;size=x_medium&amp;output-format=jpg&amp;output-quality=70"
          class="img-responsive-height" alt="Cozy room - Prague centre Old Town" data-urls="[output-format=jpg&amp;output-quality=70&quot;, &quot;https://a1.mu &quotut-format=jpg&amp;output-quality=70&quot;]">
        </div>
```

I want to get the src="https://a2.muscache.com/ic/pictures/19208233/4d8e6c0d_original.jpg only using Regex expression. I have tried so far

> class=\"listing-img-container media-cover text-center\">\n(.*)

but it's capturing me the whole long link..

Comment: This is almost what i am looking for.. But my file contains more uneeded SRC's.. so if could somehow scrape only the SRC of this specifc DIV? class=\"listing-img-container media-cover text-center\">\n \\src="[^"]+" or somehow?

Comment: added the modified regex.

Comment: Regex is not the most appropriate tool for parsing HTML. Have you considered using a structured DOM? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Well i am scraping information from divs with regex expressions and PHP... DOM was too complex for me to work with so i am doing it with PHP and regex_scrape

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="listing-img-container media-cover text-center">[\s\S]*?src="([^"]+?\.jpg)
```

Try this.Grab the capture.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/zU7dA5/19

Comment: Almost there! appreciate the help! can we make it untill the .jpg like https://a2.muscache.com/ic/pictures/19208233/4d8e6c0d_original.jpg?interpolation=lanczos-none&amp;size=x_medium&amp;output-format=jpg&amp;output-quality=70"

https://a2.muscache.com/ic/pictures/19208233/4d8e6c0d_original.jpg

And exclude PNG?

Comment: Please have a look: http://regex101.com/r/eE7pM4/1
It scrapes now the second SRC it sees however the DIV is set to the correct one.. what could be the issue?

Comment: @IlanBylakov the first one you wanted had `png` not `jpg`.Soit was catching second one.I have modified the regex.see http://regex101.com/r/eE7pM4/2

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regex, use a DOM parser like [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) together with [DOMXpath](http://php.net/manual/de/class.domxpath.php). For Xpath [also have a look here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp).

Now put all your HTML into a `DOMDocument` and search within with `Xpath`:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$imageNodes = $xpath->query('//div[@class="listing-img-container media-cover text-center"]/img');
$src = $imageNodes->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
```

I turned off warnings for `$dom->loadHtml()` since there are some due to incorrect HTML, but this does not influence functionallity.

If you don't want the whole `src` but just the part before `?` add

```
$explode = explode('?', $src, 2);
$src = $explode[0];
```